Why are cookies not sent with cross origin image request for image referenced in css?
Why are cookies not sent with cross origin image request for image referenced in css, but cookies are sent when the image is referenced in an <img> src attribute?

Page is hosted at host1.mydomain.net.
Images are hosted at host2.mydomain.net.
There are cookies on host2.mydomain.net.

CORS headers on the images:

access-control-allow-origin: https://host1.mydomain.net
access-control-allow-credentials: true

    <style>
        #imagemask {
            mask-image: url("https://host2.mydomain.net/images/imagemask.png");
        }
    
    </style>
    
    
    <div id="imagemask"></div>
    <img src="https://host2.mydomain.net/images/image.png" />


Both image requests have Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
The request for image.png has Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors and sends the cookie.
The request for imagemask.png has Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors and does not send the cookie.


You can use attribute crossorigin in <img> tag (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#crossorigin) to enable CORS request that is same as the url() made.
Default <img> tag is non-CORS request, so Sec-Fetch-Mode is no-cors and the browser sends the cookies.
